# with (nolock) in hive equivqlent to sql (nolock)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, hive

I want to execute a select query in Hive, but it took so long I decided to check my table lock status. Apparently the table has been locked by some ongoing queries.

I know in such cases SQL has **with (nolock)** that I can apply on a table. Is there something similar or equivalent in hive ?

```
  Sample sql query : select * from table a with (nolock)

  Equivalent query in hive is what I am looking for ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control concurrency locking with `hive.support.concurrency` property. See: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/configuration+properties#ConfigurationProperties-hive.support.concurrency

In your case, just set it to `false` (true is the default) before executing the query:

```
set hive.support.concurrency=false
```

You can confirm that concurrency is turn off by looking into hive_beeline log for the following line:

```
INFO  : Concurrency mode is disabled, not creating a lock manager
```